# How to fix bizarre spanning behaviour of div container

Tags: html, layout

For this problem, you will need to refer to a live website at https://www.ashenglowgaming.com/.

You will need to resize your browser by hand to reproduce the problematic behaviour I'm observing.

The problem is illustrated thus.  The red box in question is the `div` I'm talking about.  In the first two responsive modes, the box behaves fine.  It is in the third responsive mode that the problem emerges:

[image]

When the browser width is > 1024px, the `div` in question behaves fine - it is circled in red:

[image]

However, when the browser width is < 1024px (responsive mode), the grey border of the div is seen to span other areas of the website.  In essence, it is *as if* the opening `<div>` tag was relocated to the start of the html document.  Now the `div` box encompasses container 2 also, in the original figure.

[image]

Can someone please help me to diagnose and resolve the bug?

**Edit 1: to clarify, the desired behaviour is that the red box boundaries contains the Recent Posts list, and nothing else.  The border should contain this and this only.  It should definitely not sprawl over into container 2.**

**Edit 2: For some of you, this new information could generate some leads - I ran the raw html through Tidy HTML for a list of html errors, and the following came up:**

```
line 1348 column 1698 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1356 column 1 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1355 column 1 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1356 column 370 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1355 column 1 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1357 column 1 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1356 column 370 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1357 column 83 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1357 column 138 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1357 column 144 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1378 column 1 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1377 column 1 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1378 column 308 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1377 column 1 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1379 column 1 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1378 column 308 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1379 column 74 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1379 column 121 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1379 column 127 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1400 column 1 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1399 column 1 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1400 column 436 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1399 column 1 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1401 column 1 - Warning: <div> isn't allowed in <h1> elements
line 1400 column 436 - Info: <h1> previously mentioned
line 1401 column 74 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1401 column 136 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1401 column 142 - Warning: discarding unexpected </div>
line 1363 column 44 - Warning: <img> lacks "alt" attribute
line 1439 column 61 - Warning: <a> attribute "href" lacks value
line 3 column 1 - Warning: <html> proprietary attribute "xmlns:fb"
line 3 column 1 - Warning: <html> proprietary attribute "xmlns:addthis"
Info: Document content looks like HTML5
Tidy found 23 warnings and 0 errors!
```

**Edit 3: More broadly, container 1 is also spanning container 2 also in Responsive mode 3, not just the red box widget inside it.**

**Edit 4: When I download the raw html output onto my desktop and open it from there - and hence in an environment removed from the hosting server, the undesired spanning behaviour of container 1 was not observed.**

Comment: Can you post the related html and css

Comment: In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide both your CSS and your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: I thought to do so, but as I didn't design the theme myself, it is immensely difficult for me to distil a minimal example - especially as the complete html document is huge and complex, and the document itself is compiled server-side by combining multiple documents dynamically.  I will work on the minimal example, but it will take some study, and in the meantime, if someone can solve the problem without my minimal example, with reference to the live source, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the diagram, there is a div containter inside (2) marked in blue.  Its original styling was `float: right`, which removed it from the flow of the document.  Changing to `float: none` causes the div below to respect its presence.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected behavior?

I changed the width of `div#uplp-list-6532` to 100% and then the border wraps the content. Is that what you are looking for?

Additionally, you can remove the padding from `div#main` in the smaller viewport and you won't have the white margin around the content.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear: I've edited the original post to clarify the desired behaviour.

Comment: I did some digging but can't come up with anything. I'm on a laptop so it makes it harder, and there are a ton of divs to dissect. Finding the culprit will be really tedious I think. For a quick work around until you figure it out, you can remove the border upon the smaller viewport. That is just a band aid though. Good luck.

Comment: Potentially to narrow down the culprit - see my **Edit 2** to the original post.    You may be able to derive some insight from this.

Comment: I found the bastard!  Solution above! :)